# how does js bind() function work in details?

Tags: javascript, binding

```
    const unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
    const slice = Function.prototype.apply.bind(unboundSlice);
    slice(arguments);
```

This is a code snippet in MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
I want to know how it works in detail.
it says in the docs:

> bind() is also helpful in cases where you want to create a shortcut to a function which requires a specific this value.
> Take Array.prototype.slice(), for example, which you want to use for converting an array-like object to a real array. You could create a shortcut like this:

```
const slice = Array.prototype.slice;

// ...

slice.apply(arguments);
```

> With bind(), this can be simplified.In the following piece of code, slice() is a bound function to the apply() function of Function.prototype, with the this value set to the slice() function of Array.prototype. This means that additional apply() calls can be eliminated:

```
//  same as "slice" in the previous example
const unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
const slice = Function.prototype.apply.bind(unboundSlice);

// ...

slice(arguments);
```

Comment: What specific part(s) about it do you not understand?

Comment: I use `$ = document.querySelector.bind(document)` to use `$` as shortcut sometimes but I don't understand what the second example is doing either.

Comment: I can understand this way to transform an array-like object to a real array: Array.prototype.slice.apply(arg), it's the normal usage of bind(), but the second way "a shortcut to a function which requires a specific this value. " -----               
const unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
const slice = Function.prototype.apply.bind(unboundSlice);
slice(arguments);    unboundSlice is a function, bind a function into a function??? I can 't understand why the second way does the same thing with the first one ?

Comment: and why it called a shortcut? I can realize  I  must have missed some key concept in js function or object or something else in programming that result in I can not understand the process of the second way .i want to know every little step in the second way ,what every step did and how ? finally and most importantly I want to figure out what key concept or thought in js or programming I have missed. because I feel this way to deal with function is an advanced way in programming.